# Angular 5 production issue

Tags: angular, deployment, build

I'm trying to deploy my Angular 5 app on a nginx server with the command

```
ng build --env=prod
```

But when I go on my website, there's always an error on vendor file.

The application works well when I build it within a folder like /test with the command : `ng build --env=prod --bh /test/`

I'm really lost. Is it a nginx issue ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you experience the same error with ng serve --prod ?

Comment: I tried to build it with --prod argument. The website was showing normally but FormsModule didn't worked. That's why I use environment argument

Comment: I didnt ask for build, but serve :)

Comment: Oh sorry. With serve --prod, I can't use FormModule too. And no files is created. 
The purpose is to use VestaCP with its interface. So I can't run ng serve there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify a folder with the -bh option. You specify the base href.

When you want to serve angular from the root directory simply use -bh /. Also check your index.html If there's a predefined base path.

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: Even with the command, the issue is showing up

    ng build --env=prod --bh /

Comment: SyntaxError: missing } after function body      vendor.bundle.js:2:397750

And the Nginx Config : 
https://pastebin.com/yFK7ynad

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses PathLocationStratergy by default, and when you do a prod build, it fails to make it work if we don't specify a base href explicitly.
if you don't want to specify a base href in this case you need to use HashLocationStratergy in routing.

examples 
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, **{useHash: true}**);

there is another trick
**below is not the best practice**
 after you make a prod build just change base href in index.html to **"."**.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
ng build --env=prod
```

Use

```
ng build --prod
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still struggling with production setup of angular 2/4/5 app + Nginx, then here is the complete solution:

Suppose you want to deploy your angular app at HOST: `http://example.com` and PORT: `8080`
Note - HOST and PORT might be different in your case.

Make sure you have `<base href="/">` in you index.html head tag.

1. Firstly, go to your angular repo (i.e. /home/user/helloWorld) path at your machine.
2. Then build /dist for your production server using the following command:

   ng build --prod --base-href http://example.com:8080
3. Now copy /dist (i.e. /home/user/helloWorld/dist) folder from your machine's angular repo to the remote machine where you want to host your production server.
4. Now login to your remote server and add following nginx server configuration.

   ```
   server {

       listen 8080;

       server_name http://example.com;

       root /path/to/your/dist/location;

       # eg. root /home/admin/helloWorld/dist

       index index.html index.htm;

       location / {

           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

           # This will allow you to refresh page in your angular app. Which will not give error 404.

       }

   }
   ```
5. Now restart nginx.
6. That's it !! Now you can access your angular app at http://example.com:8080

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: I'll try asap :) ! Do you have any idea for apache ?  It's just redirecting / to /index.html ?